# How to pass a parameter which isn't used in invoking function?

Tags: haskell, lambda, scope

I wrote two functions. My first function receives two parameters, `f` a function, and `n`. `f` is arbitrary function and `n` is a stop value.

My first function looks like so

```
series f 0 = (f 0)
series f n = seriesInt f n 0 0

-- Not a main question, but how can both these functions series and 
-- seriesInt be written as one function?     

seriesInt f n acc i | i <= n = seriesInt f n (acc + (f i)) (i+1)
                    | otherwise = acc
```

My second function is this

```
taylor i x | x == 1 = 1
           | otherwise = ((-1)^i / (myFac t)) * (x^t)
   where 
   t = (2 * i + 1)
```

For this function I need two parameters, `i` and `x`.

Parameter `i` will be passed from my `series` function, but how can I pass  parameter `x` to this function?

I'm supposing, I need a Lambda expression for that?

Comment: after editing, I understood your first question.  You write them in one function using `where`: `series f n = seriesInt f n 0 0 where seriesInt f n acc i ...`. Indent the `where` block. Then only `series` can be used from other code. `seriesInt` will be invisible outside the `series` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you pass it a lambda function, `(\ i -> taylor i x)`, like so:

```
foo n x = seriesInt (\ i -> taylor i x) n 0 0
```

You could use as e.g. `map (foo 1000) [1..10]`.

The lambda function is defined in the scope of `x`, so it can use it. A new lambda function is defined by the call to `foo` for each `x` that `foo` gets called with.

Comment: Also I wrote this in the editor 'foo n x = seriesInt (\ i -> taylor i x) n 0 0' but which function should I invoke in GHCi and how? I'm trying to invoke series function, but it doesn't work.

Comment: define `foo n x = series (\ i -> taylor i x) n`. then call `let x = 1 in foo 1000 x` or `let x = 101.345 in foo 10 x` or whatever `x` makes sense for your definition of `taylor`. what are you calculating, a sine or something?

Comment: instead of calculating each i th term of the series in isolation it can be much better to devise a way to calculate them in sequence, e.g. via the known ratio between the consecutive terms, so that `series = iterate next_term initial_term` or something.

Comment: I write exactly this in GHCi  foo 1000  1 and I receive an error message '• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘it’ ......'  yes I am trying to calculate sin(x)

Comment: you should declare a type for your taylor function then like `taylor :: Int -> Double -> Double` or something. you write it on a separate line above the defintion of `taylor i x = ...` Either put into a source file, or use `:{` and `:}` to enter and exit the multiline editing mode of GHCi. Also, don't use 1000. Use 10, 20, and see what happens.

Comment: I receive two error massages, when I wrote head line 'taylor :: Int -> Double -> Double'  first • Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
and second Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Double’ and It doesn't work taylor::(Eq a)=> a -> a -> a -> a too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185912/discussion-between-will-ness-and-haskell).